# Mysql Instance not available to local user account

Tags: mysql

I installed an instance of MySQL 5.1. The service runs fine when I log on as Administrator. But I am unable to run the instance using a local user account. The instance runs in 'localhost'. I get Error 5: Access Denied when I try to start the service from the local account. Should I elevate privileges to run the service? How do I do it? I tried to Run As Admin and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-management-sql.html): you need to `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` permissions specifically to the `user@localhost`.